# In vim append 'U' to all numbers

Tags: regex, vim

I want to go to a c file and append 'U' to any numbers that do not have a `U` already.

so

```
int a = 5 + 5;
int b = 32 + 3U;
```

Should be

```
int a = 5U + 5U;
int b = 32U + 3U;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the possible U that shall not be duplicated, I'd say

```
:%s/\<\d\+\>/&U/g
```

that should be good enough in most cases (/filetypes) regarding usual word boundaries.

PS: storing an unsigned into a signed `int` is fishy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, the example was not well written, it would have been a uint32_t.